# Calculate percentage based on status of max per group in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Given the dataset below, I'd like to calculate percentage of status over unique count of workflow.

```
id,workflow,status
1,A,FAILURE
2,A,ABORTED
3,A,SUCCESS
4,A,SUCCESS
1,B,FAILURE
2,B,SUCCESS
3,B,FAILURE
1,C,FAILURE
2,C,FAILURE
1,D,FAILURE
2,D,SUCCESS
3,D,FAILURE
4,D,FAILURE
5,D,FAILURE
```

Always refer to the status of max id.

```
A - SUCCESS (refer to max id 4)
B - FAILURE (refer to max id 3)
C - FAILURE (refer to max id 2)
D - FAILURE (refer to max id 5)
```

Expected aggregated results as follow:

```
unique count of workflow: 4   // workflow A, B, C, and D
SUCCESS: (1/4) * 100 = 25%    // workflow A
FAILURE: (3/4) * 100 = 75%    // workflow B, C, and D
```

Appreciate it if you can advise the query to get the 25% (SUCCESS) and 75% (FAILURE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "status_success": {
        "type": "long",
        "script": {
          "source": "if (doc['status'].value == 'SUCCESS') {emit(1)} else {emit(0)}"
        }
      },
      "status_failure": {
        "type": "long",
        "script": {
          "source": "if (doc['status'].value == 'FAILURE') {emit(1)} else {emit(0)}"
        }
      },
      "workflow": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{}}
{"id": 1, "workflow": "A", "status": "FAILURE"}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 2, "workflow": "A", "status": "ABORTED"}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 3, "workflow": "A", "status": "SUCCESS"}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 4, "workflow": "A", "status": "SUCCESS"}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 1, "workflow": "B", "status": "FAILURE"}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 2, "workflow": "B", "status": "SUCCESS"}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 3, "workflow": "B", "status": "FAILURE"}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 1, "workflow": "C", "status": "FAILURE"}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 2, "workflow": "C", "status": "FAILURE"}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 1, "workflow": "D", "status": "FAILURE"}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 2, "workflow": "D", "status": "SUCCESS"}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 3, "workflow": "D", "status": "FAILURE"}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 4, "workflow": "D", "status": "FAILURE"}
{"index":{}}
{"id": 5, "workflow": "D", "status": "FAILURE"}


GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_workflow": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "workflow"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_status": {
          "top_metrics": {
            "metrics": [
              {"field": "status_success"},
              {"field": "status_failure"}
              ],
              "sort": {
                "id": "desc"
              }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "success_rate": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "by_workflow>top_status[status_success]",
        "gap_policy": "skip",
        "format": "#%"
      }
    },
    "failure_rate": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "by_workflow>top_status[status_failure]",
        "gap_policy": "skip",
        "format": "#%"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'd like to clarify if `status_success` and `status_failure` are scripted fields? In this case, does it mean that I should create them in my index pattern?

Comment: Yes, they are generated during indexing. If reindexing is difficult, you can replace them with [runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/runtime-mapping-fields.html) the syntax is the same, except they go into "runtime" section instead of "mapping" section and you can updated your mapping without reindexing.

Comment: Thanks @imotov. I use `runtime_mappings` and managed to get the expected results with your suggestion.

Comment: Hi @imotov, I'd like to create a pie on the aggregated results, e.g. `success_rate`, `failure_rate`. Any insights will be appreciated. How can I transform the `success_rate` and `failure_rate` into a dataset that can be used for Vega/Vega-lite pie creation.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with vega. Since you are asking these questions I feel like you might benefit from creating a separate index that would use both workflow+id as an id. Or use workflow as id and id as version. This way all your requests will become much simpler because you will only have the latest state in the index and you will not have to spend all this energy selecting it.